# Hardware to wire ESP32 directly to 110VAC?

Tags: esp32, ac-power

I'd like to fit an ESP32 directly into a single gang (North American) electrical box with enough room left over to fit a typical light switch over the top of it (these are usually pretty shallow, and the box itself is almost 3" deep).

What sort of hardware would I need to wire one of these into AC directly?

I'm trying to solve the problem of not having batteries everywhere in my house, where I spend 8 hours a week hunting down dead batteries and replacing them. I have no clue how it's become acceptable to design products like exterior door locks with batteries. I suspect it's a stock market scam to boost share prices for Energizer.

The National Electrical Code apparently tolerates mixing low voltage and high voltage in a single junction box for communication devices, supposing that it meets several criteria:

- The wires/conductors have at least 6mm of separation on the board and within the box
- The wires/conductors for the low voltage portion meet the same insulation standards as those for the high voltage (no cheapskate jumper wires, in other words)
- All components are clearly marked as low/high voltage

This could (in theory) meet code.

This is an IoT question and not a "how do you power a general purpose computing device" question because:

1. It requires a networked computing device small enough to fit into a single gang junction box.
2. It's for the purpose of connecting a sensor and/or an actuator to a home automation system.
3. It would require hardware specific to such a device, nothing general purpose would suffice.
4. The very premise of the question rests on the challenge of putting such devices where they have not tended to fit before.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. [Edit](https://iot.stackexchange.com/posts/6209/edit) the question to describe the *actual* problem you are trying to solve with this and we might be able to suggest a better alternative.

Comment: @hardillb That's the actual problem I'm trying to solve. I've found web pages that describe some strategies for this (most involve multiple fuses and other safety mechanisms). None are retail solutions, and I can't exactly make my own PCBs. And if I could, none are entirely consistent on how such a thing should work.

Comment: Again what is the actual problem you want to solve? Are you trying to power the ESP32 from 110VAC? Are you trying to monitor the voltage or current of the AC line? Are you trying to switch the AC line? "Wire ESP32 directly to 110VAC" means more to you than to us.

Comment: No it's not, say what the ESP32 will be doing, otherwise you should be asking this on the [electrical engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) site, not here.

Comment: How to fit an esp32 (or esp8266) into a single gang electrical box hooked directly to 110VAC (North American) power. Nothing more, nothing less. The size probably isn't a limitation itself, nor heat dissipation. But I want it in the box, and not taped to the outside of a wall with a wall wart plugged into an outlet 6 feet away. There are no other problems to solve other than this, and no alternatives worth exploring.

Comment: Please edit the question as asked. And you still haven't answered my question about WHAT the ESP32 will be doing. If you can't answer that question then you really are asking in the wrong place

Comment: See https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/86116/how-to-power-esp32-with-230v-ac note that heat dissipation IS an issue, and that in many countries plugging something like this is subject to code, and may not be allowed unless the device is certified. The risk of electric shock or fire really exists.

Comment: `how to fit an object into a box?` is not an IoT question

Comment: @hardillb I can't edit the question as asked. What I want to do is quite simple. There will be some small peripheral attached to the ESP, I don't need help with that. I just need it in a single gang, powered off AC. There aren't really any alternatives or substitutes here.

Comment: @jsotola It's a good thing I asked "what object do I need, to put it into the box" instead, eh?

Comment: @JohnO without explaining the purpose of the object, it still is not an IoT question

Comment: Folks please keep things civil in comments. For clarity, what do you mean by "I can't edit the question as asked?" Simply click the [edit] button. Also, [it is imperative](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that you demonstrate how this is about IoT and not generic computing/hardware - **in the question, not in comments.**  If you want to keep the question open *you will have to [edit] in the required info.*  As an experienced SE user, I expect that you understand that each site has clearly stated requirements for questions; failure to abide by those standards will result in closure.

Comment: The reason I asked for the actual problem being solved is because knowing what sensor and duty cycle could lead to challenging the assumptions that AC power is required. A well set up ESP8266 & sensor can run for years on a liPO battery that will easily fit in the space mentioned, which would remove the need to build/find a suitable safe power supply

Comment: It is worth noting that even people like Philips prefer to have battery-powered devices to put into switch wall boxes rather than actually power off the available AC wires. The security concerns are not trivial.

Comment: @hardillb The reason AC power is required is because I want this in the wall, not something stapled to the wall with a wall wart running off to a power outlet 5 ft away. The box already has AC power. NEC says that for "communication devices" it's acceptable to mix high and low voltage together, assuming conductors are at least 6mm away and the insulation on low voltage is the same as that required for the high voltage. UL certification is the only remaining problem, and I thought if I asked maybe someone would even point me at something that was. In general, I loathe batteries.

Comment: @anonymous2 I understand the sociology of this for certain. This is an IoT question because I am asking for hardware for an IoT device, and the hardware would not be meaningful to a generic computing device which could not fit in the box. Furthermore, this is specific to the challenges of installing an IoT device in a location not easily installed. You've allowed many questions like it before. But it doesn't matter whether I follow the rules so much as to whether my questions are ones that people *feel* is normal, and once you all dogpiled it was dead as a doornail.

Comment: @JohnO thank you for the edits - it definitely helps clarify that this is an IoT topic. I have editted out the profanity and the speculation superfluous to the post; feel free to take concerns about how the site runs to [meta]. Also, I would like to remind everyone to adhere to our [code of conduct](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/conduct). There is a time and place for constructive disagreement, but assuming bad faith is not acceptable. Please take concerns about the functioning of the site to Meta in a wholesome, friendly manner. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Tasmota project, which allows you to run custom code on cheap off-the-shelf ESP8266 and ESP32 mains devices.

You can probably buy some cheap hardware that does what you want, or will do what you want with very minor modifications.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. I install Tasmota on all of mine, getting ready to gut a Broadlink RM Mini 3 and replace the board with a D1 Mini board just for that.

Answer (score 0):

I still think this is a bad idea, but 5 seconds (it was in the list returned by the top none advert hit) of googling for "3.3v from 110v ac" turns up the following:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002904403184.html?spm=a2g0o.search0304.0.0.1e926182Gzrtca&algo_pvid=d4d24c4a-730a-4050-a2d1-76b559c4d938&algo_exp_id=d4d24c4a-730a-4050-a2d1-76b559c4d938-3

The dimensions appear to meet your requirements.

I expect it to get warn sealed up in the wall, so when one burns your house down you were warned,